# In react-native how to get select tab value or index

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In react-native how to get select tab value or index. I am rendering API data in a tab. In our tab multiple dates are coming.

I want to save selected tab value like which date is selected.

Can someone help?

```
 <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />} style={styles.Card_background_Margin} initialPage={0}
                      onChangeTab={(Tab, index) => this.tabChanged(Tab, index)}>


                      {  this.state.dateList.map((lists) => {
                        return(
                      <Tab heading= {lists.items} style={styles.Tab_background}>
                        <ScheduleDays navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                      </Tab>

                      )
                  })
                }

                </Tabs>
```

And here I am calling that function but in an alert, it's coming `[object][object]`, and for the index, it's coming `undefined`. If I am selecting any other tab then this function is working.

```
tabChanged(Tab, index){
  alert(Tab);
}
```

Comment: please help anyone...

Comment: Instead of alert, try with "console.log(Tab)". You will get the values. (You can try "react-native log-android").

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not giving me the selcted value or index

Comment: Could you provide the output, which is getting printed in you console ? Also, check for both the values, Tab and index.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue...

initialPage you have to define in constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
           this.state = {
          pageNumber: 1
    }
```

After that call you method here, you will get selected heading value in alert for me it's working fine.

```
tabChanged(ref){
   alert(ref);
   }

<Tabs
   renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />} style={styles.Card_background_Margin}
   initialPage={this.state.pageNumber}
   onChangeTab={({ ref }) => this.tabChanged(ref.props.heading)}
>
   {
      this.state.dateList.map((lists) => {
         return(
            <Tab heading= {lists.items}  style={styles.Tab_background}>
               <ScheduleDays navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            </Tab>
         )
      }) 
   }  
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, because index gives back an object. But the object consist of the three properties (i, ref, from) so with i.i you can get the index of the tab.
So in your example

`tabChanged(Tab, index){
  alert(Tab.i);
}`

should work.